# ASP.NET Zero: How to add new Area in another project?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have created a modular application based on Zero Framework following this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/princeppy/ae0f24417f6ccdc7ccc73587ed9f1769)
Because that tut didn't guide to create an Area in module Web. So I decided to create another area (named Payment) in root web project.

1. **Areas/F1**       <--my default area
2. **Areas/Payment**  <--new area

I created a very simple controller (inherited from project controller base class) like this:

```
 public class BankCodeController : FastOneControllerBase
    {
        // GET: Payment/BankCode
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

...and my Index.cshtml

```
@using FastOne.Web.Navigation
@{
    ViewBag.CurrentPageName = PageNames.App.Payment.BankCode;
}
<div class="row margin-bottom-5">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="page-head">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1>
                    <span>BankCode</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="portlet light">
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <p>BANK CODE CONTENT COMES HERE!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I faced the error as below when I tried to access that view

> The controller for path '/Payment/BankCode' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.

```
> Line 40:     @RenderSection("Styles", false) 
> Line 41:      
> Line 42:     @Html.Action("TenantCustomCss", "Layout") 
> Line 43:  
> Line 44:     <script type="text/javascript">
```

Hope anyone could help me on this error some guide to create this Area in module Web project (in the tutorial). Thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I found this solution in ASPNET Zero forum

Since I use `_Layout.cshtml` of `F1` area, this error happens.
I fixed it by adding `F1` area name to `@Html.Action` usages in `_Layout.cshtml`.

For example

```
@Html.Action("Header", "Layout") becomes @Html.Action("Header", "Layout", new { area = "F1" })
@Html.Action("Sidebar", "Layout", new { currentPageName = ViewBag.CurrentPageName }) becomes @Html.Action("Sidebar", "Layout", new { currentPageName = ViewBag.CurrentPageName, area = "F1" })
```